# Objective-C: (Weird) UIButton frame NSLogs different coordinates vs. where it displays (and receives touches)

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uiview, uibutton

**Updated Solution:** The principle problem was that my speed calculation was returning a whole number - `0` for all cases except for the object at index 3, where it was `1` - despite being labeled instantiated as a `float`. The result? The buttons were in an 'infinite' animation (an animation with 0 speed) from origin to destination.

////////////////////////////////////////

**Weird:** I am drawing some buttons on my view programmatically, and while troubleshooting my code I discovered that the buttons' frame/position/center (in Location A) differs from where they actually display (Location B). This is my first time coming across this phenomena..

(To make matters worse, I'm using `hitTest:withEvent:` and returning buttons based on their frame, so I am actually tracking hits (and firing actions) on touches to Location A, even though the buttons themselves are being displayed in Location B.)

**Notes & Caveats:** One of the buttons appears correctly. I don't know why. All buttons animate correctly, because the animations run off their frames.

I'm sure I'm missing something in my code, but I've been over it for hours and given that I the frame is reporting wrong I need more eyes!

**Diagram:**

```
+-----------------------+
|(mainV)                |
|                       |
|                 +----+|
|                 |(sB)||
|                 +----+|
|                 +----+|
|                 |(sB)||
|                 +----+|
|                 +----+|
|                 |(sB)||
|                 +----+|
|                 +----+|
|                 |(sB)||
|                 +----+|
|                 +----+|
|                 |(dW)||
|                 +----+|
|+---------------------+|
||(mV)                 ||
|+---------------------+|
+-----------------------+
```

**Legend:**

- (mainV) = main view/view controller, parent view of everything
- (mV) = menuView, subview of (mainV)
- (dW) = drawButton, subview of (mV), and the 'anchor' from which I build my other buttons
- (sB) = instance of sizeButton, subview of (mV), using `hitTest:withEvent:` to get touches outside of the superview's frame

**Code & Comments:**

*Central Button Creation Method, where I initially call & create the buttons, most vars are instance variables*

```
- (void)addSizeSubButtons {

    BOOL showAnimation = NO;

    if ([drawSizeButtonsArray count] == 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < kNumberOfDrawSizes; i++) {

            // this method is defined below
            // short story is it makes 4 buttons and adds them to an array
            [self makeSizeButton];
        }

        showAnimation = YES;
    }

    // drawSizeButtonsArray is the array from before - see makeSizeButtons below
    for (UIButton *sizeButton in drawSizeButtonsArray) {

        int buttonIndex = [drawSizeButtonsArray indexOfObject:sizeButton];

        // drawButton is my unofficial anchor point - its center is {287.8, -24.25}
        // sizing code in general works and I don't believe is at play here
        // see (dW) in the diagram above..
        [sizeButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                        0,
                                        drawButton.bounds.size.height * kStackButtonRatio,
                                        drawButton.bounds.size.height * kStackButtonRatio)];

        CGPoint position = CGPointMake(drawButton.center.x,
                                       drawButton.center.y - sizeButton.bounds.size.height * (1.1 + buttonIndex));

        [sizeButton.layer setPosition:position];

        NSLog(@"sizeButton made at %@ named %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(sizeButton.center),sizeButton);

        // NSLog Output (all coords relative to (mV) from legend above:
        // sizeButton made at {287.8, -66.6} (this is loop #1/sizeButton atIndex:0)
        // sizeButton made at {287.8, -105.1} (this is loop #2/sizeButton atIndex:1)
        // sizeButton made at {287.8, -143.6} (this is loop #3/sizeButton atIndex:2)
        // sizeButton made at {287.8, -182.1} (this is loop #4/sizeButton atIndex:3)
        // note: I have tested that the buttons are all different/at different memory addresses
        // --------------------
        // HOWEVER, visual display locations are as follows:
        // button atIndex:0 @ {287.8, -24.25} (remember this is the same as drawButton!)
        // button atIndex:1 @ {287.8, -24.25} (also wrong, and also hidden behind drawButton)
        // button atIndex:2 @ {287.8, -24.25} (three in a row in the wrong place)
        // button atIndex:3 @ {287.8, -182.1} (!! HARK! this one is actually in the right place.. no clue why one is and the other three are not)

        [sizeButton.layer setCornerRadius:sizeButton.bounds.size.width / 7.5];
    }

    // animations are actually working as desired, because they run off the frame
    // as soon as the animation kicks off, buttons all appear in the right place
    // and take the correct action; still, i will include the core method just in case
    if (showAnimation == YES) {

        for (UIButton *sizeButton in drawSizeButtonsArray) {

            // so my button is moving FROM its anchor TO its actual center
            CGPoint origin = drawButton.center;
            CGPoint destination = sizeButton.center;

            // this is just to create a visual effect
            float speed = ( [drawSizeButtonsArray indexOfObject:sizeButton] + 1 ) / [drawSizeButtonsArray count];

            // my central animation method, included below
            CABasicAnimation *slideButton = [self slideButton:sizeButton
                                                    fromPoint:origin
                                                      toPoint:destination
                                                      atSpeed:speed];

            [sizeButton.layer addAnimation:slideButton
                                    forKey:@"slideSizeButtonAnimation"];
        }

    }
}
```

*Button Creator Helper/Worker Method called from above*

```
- (void)makeSizeButton {

    UIButton *sizeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [drawSizeButtonsArray addObject:sizeButton];

    // button presses
    [sizeButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [sizeButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(drawSizeButtonPressed:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // TO DO: remove these debug titles and replace with dots
    [sizeButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[drawSizeButtonsArray indexOfObject:sizeButton]]
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sizeButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor]
                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [sizeButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    // show it!
    [self addSubview:sizeButton];
    [self sendSubviewToBack:sizeButton];

}
```

*Animation Helper Method*

```
- (CABasicAnimation *)slideButton:(UIButton *)button
                        fromPoint:(CGPoint)origin
                          toPoint:(CGPoint)destination
                          atSpeed:(float)speed{

    // now show animation
    CABasicAnimation *slideAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    [slideAnimation setDelegate:self];

    // from & to values
    [slideAnimation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:origin]];
    [slideAnimation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:destination]];

    // easing in and out.. oh yeah!
    [slideAnimation setDuration:kAnimationTiming / speed];
    CAMediaTimingFunction *easeInOut = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    [slideAnimation setTimingFunction:easeInOut];

    NSLog(@"slide animation from %@ to %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(origin),NSStringFromCGPoint(destination));

    // NSLog Output: (all these values are correct/what I intended)
    // AND recall that all animations display properly!
    // in fact, judging by NSLog, everything is working fine.. but visually it is not
    // slide animation from {287.8, -24.25} to {287.8, -66.6} (for button atIndex:0)
    // slide animation from {287.8, -24.25} to {287.8, -105.1} (for button atIndex:1)
    // slide animation from {287.8, -24.25} to {287.8, -143.6} (for button atIndex:2)
    // slide animation from {287.8, -24.25} to {287.8, -182.1} (for button atIndex:3)

    return slideAnimation;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this problem still occur if you disable your animations?

Are you applying transforms to any of your views?

One thing I'd note: it's weird to set the frame of a UIView and then adjust its layer's position. How about using `[sizeButton setCenter:position]` rather than accessing the layer. I don't think that's the problem, but it might have something to do with it. Similarly, why not use UIView's animation methods rather than diving into CABasicAnimation land?

Comment: ahh jesus! of course disabling the animations is an obvious troubleshooting step given the problem. that *does* allow the buttons to show up properly - so now to figure out what's actually going on.. ;)  p.s. definitely tried `setCenter:` earlier to no avail - what are the pros and cons of each approach?  p.s.s. feeling kind of dumb, but i didn't realize `UIView` had its own animations.. reading further now.

Comment: In general, I try to use UIView-level methods for Apple's UIView subclasses, because if you manipulate their layers directly, you occasionally run into trouble. If you try the UIView animation approach and setCenter: and are still running into problems, post your updated code and I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Ahh, so the problem with my `speed` calculation (or rather its type). Still dialing in my implementation, but looking at the animation was the proper troubleshooting path, so marking your suggestion as the answer. Thanks Jesse! I'll focus on UIView's animation stuff next project, or next time I hit a snag.